# Javascript sort by object with an array with ES6 fails

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, ecmascript-6

What am trying to do is to order the above items with the length of variant such that after the order the second item will be first since it has 3 items in the variant array

I have the following data structure and code:

```js
var items = [
 {name: 'one', variant: [{id: 1, name: 'ABS'}, ]},  
 {name: 'second', variant: [{id: 1, name: 'BTC'}, {id: 2, name: 'SAM'}, {id: 2, name: 'KXD'}]}
]

console.log(items.sort((a, b) => a.variant.length > b.variant.length))
```

But this does not sort the items. 
What am i missing as i would like to do this in ES6

Comment: Note per e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort that the callback to sort probably shouldn't just return a boolean

Comment: `.sort((a, b) => b.variant.length - a.variant.length)` will do it

Answer (score 2):

You have to return 1, -1 , or 0
If you want to change to order, swap 1 with -1.

```
items.sort((a,b)=>{
        if(a.variant.length > b.variant.length)
            return 1;
        else if (b.variant.length > a.variant.length)
            return -1;
        else // if a.variant.length === b.variant.length
            return 0;
     })
```